# Plotting raster over openstreet map after reading in with rasterio

Tags: python, rasterio

I have read in a simple raster with rasterio that I would like to plot over an OSM map (interactive if possible).
- My first hurdle is plotting raster with real world coordinates rather using default 0,0 origin.
- Second is finding library to plot interactively on (folium, cartopy, etc). I have failed to implement raster overlay on these

Here's the ipynb: https://github.com/arnawldo/geospatial-scratch/blob/master/rasterio.ipynb

Comment: Could you expand on what you have already tried and what exactly it is you are having problems with?

Comment: I have tried the image overlay function for folium but it nothing is rendered. Mplleaflet raises a Not implemented error when adding ax object with raster plotted from rasterio's plot function. Cartopy's docs have me lost on how to plot rasters because the preprocessing needed is hard to grasp. Can I see an example of a raster tif in utm projection plotted against an openstreetmap or any other kind of interactive web mercator background ?